# {How/why} {could I have missed/did I miss} watching this movie till now?

Tags: sentence, auxiliary-verbs

How/why could I have missed watching this movie till now?

OR

How/why did I miss watching this movie till now?

I'm confused about how to use this sentence. I did research on these sentences but I became confused a lot. Could anyone explain how to frame this sentence?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the research you mention in the title, together with your conclusions or partial conclusions based on that research.

Comment: I won't suggest adding "have" in first sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with: "How could I have missed watching this movie until now?"

It is basically a shorter way of saying "*How is it that I could have* missed watching this movie until now?"

The word "why" is typically used when asking for a reason, but your sentence implies "how could this happen?", so I think "How" is a better fit.